# How to add a bitmap image as background for BlackBerry Custom Dialog box

Tags: blackberry

I know about creating Custom Dialog box by overriding Paint and sublayout methods. I want to add a plain bitmap image as background to the custom dialog box that I am creating. Anybody knows any solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563352/custom-pop-up-with-no-black-background-in-blackberry/13564998#13564998

Check out this question 
It works

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for

```
backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("background.png");
//Override the paint method to draw the background image.
    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        //Draw the background image and then call paint.
        graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, 240, 240, backgroundBitmap, 0, 0);
        super.paint(graphics);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but it dint help. I have already tried your code