# Custom Pop up with no Black background in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, dialog, popup

I want to remove the black background in Popup field
i know we use applyTheme method in blackberry to subdue its effect but dunno how to use it 
I want to remove the black background and use an image instead .

I have tried this method

```
protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.applyTheme(arg0, arg1);
}
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494643/dialog-box-background-color-on-blackberry

Comment: This question is **NOT** a duplicate of the one linked in the comment above.  People should be careful about closing questions.  Asking how to make a popup with an image background is not the same as asking how to change the background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class CustomDialogBox extends PopupScreen {

    Bitmap mDialogImg=null;
    public CustomDialogBox(Bitmap dialogImg) {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(),Field.FOCUSABLE);
        this.mDialogImg=dialogImg;
        VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager() {
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {

                graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, mDialogImg.getWidth(), mDialogImg.getHeight(), mDialogImg, 0, 0);
            };

            protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

                super.sublayout(mDialogImg.getWidth(), mDialogImg.getHeight());
                super.setExtent(mDialogImg.getWidth(), mDialogImg.getHeight());
            }
        };

        add(vfm);
    }

    protected void applyTheme() {
    }

}
```

I tried the following program and it works perfectly fine
i added a Bitmap image to a vertical field manager and then 
using the method

`applyTheme()` as follows

```java
protected void applyTheme() {
}
```

i do get the required results